# How to expand the disk space in Ubuntu 18.04 in VMware Workstation Player running in Win 10 Host

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, vmware

I'm using VMWare on Win10 as host system and Ubuntu 18.04 as guest. I had 20 GB to Ubuntu. When it complained low disk space recently, I am trying to expand it to 40GB.
I did the following steps to resize:

1. Shutdown the VM. Right click the VM and select Edit Settings. Select the hard disk you would like to extend. On the right side, make the provisioned size as large as you need it (my case it is 40GB). Click OK.
   [VM settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYSwo.png)
2. Power on the VM. Open a terminal. Log in as root. Used fdisk to added a new partition /dev/sda2 of 20GB.  At the command prompt, when I type fdisk -l, it shows,

> ```
> root@ubuntu:/# fdisk -lL
> Disk /dev/loop0: 9.1 MiB, 9510912 bytes, 18576 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/loop1: 11.6 MiB, 12161024 bytes, 23752 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/loop2: 55.3 MiB, 58007552 bytes, 113296 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/loop3: 97.7 MiB, 102445056 bytes, 200088 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/loop4: 11.5 MiB, 12042240 bytes, 23520 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/loop5: 97.1 MiB, 101777408 bytes, 198784 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
>
>
> Disk /dev/sda: 40 GiB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
> Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
> Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
> Disklabel type: dos
> Disk identifier: 0x514faf39
>
> Device     Boot    Start      End  Sectors Size Id Type
> /dev/sda1  *        2048 41940991 41938944  20G 83 Linux
> /dev/sda2       41940992 83886079 41945088  20G 83 Linux
> ```

3. But looks like this is not enough as df -h doesn't show /dev/sda2
   [df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0Wzk.png)
4. Used Gparted application to format the drive /dev/sda2 to ext4.
   [Gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJQQF.png)

But I have no clue further how to proceed for the Ubuntu use this partition. Kindly help

Comment: You will also have to edit /etc/fstab to mount your new partition automatically. Or eun `sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt` to mount it temporarily.

Comment: [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xq822qgwA8) is the only video you need to watch, if it hasn't worked for you yet.

Answer (score 1):

This should be easy to fix. The key to it is you need to boot into a live environment and work on your root partition while it is not mounted. You don’t need sda2. Try the following:

1. Backup any data you cannot afford to lose
2. Assuming you have an Ubuntu iso file place it in the VM CD drive and boot the VM from the iso as if you are installing.
3. Choose Try Ubuntu.
4. From the live environment run GParted.
5. Delete sda2. You should now unallocated space to the right of sda1
6. Expand sda1 to fill all the unallocated space. sda1 should now be 40GB.

There are plenty of YouTube videos that show how to use GParted if you’ve not used it before.

Good luck